# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),

Tags: php, mysql

I get this Error Message when I'm trying to export my data:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), salutation, chrname, name, street_name, street_remainder, zipcode, city, emai' at line 1

I can't find my fold...

```
    $sql = 'SELECT if(turnier = "Company Friends", "Company"), salutation, chrname, name, street_name, street_remainder, zipcode, city, email, tel_num, mob_num, firma, zusatz, postfach, position, telefon, mobil, bemerkungen, catering, rg_firma, rg_abt, rg_strasse, rg_plz, rg_ort, rg_kto_inhaber, rg_kto_nummer, rg_kto_blz, rg_kto_bankname, logofile, logolink, url, agb, kaution, date_format(time, "%d.%m.%y %H:%i:%s"), date_format(rg_print, "%d.%m.%y %H:%i:%s")
            FROM forms_user_reg AS a
            LEFT JOIN 1_additional_data AS b ON a.urn = b.urn
            ORDER BY turnier DESC , time ASC
            LIMIT 1000';
```

thanks

Comment: You've only specified a value for the case where your statement `true`? Try adding a third parameter for when your statement renders ´false´.

Comment: what if turnier is not 'company friends'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IF` needs 3 arguments. You've only provided 2. Change your sql to something like:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT if(turnier = "Company Friends", "Company", "Something here"), ...
```

First one is condition, second will be returned if condition is satisfied, third if not.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN turnier = "Company Friends" THEN "Company" ELSE turnier END turnier
     , salutation
     , chrname
     , name
     , street_name
     , street_remainder
     , zipcode
     , city
     , email
     , tel_num
     , mob_num
     , firma
     , zusatz
     , postfach
     , position
     , telefon
     , mobil
     , bemerkungen
     , catering
     , rg_firma
     , rg_abt
     , rg_strasse
     , rg_plz
     , rg_ort
     , rg_kto_inhaber
     , rg_kto_nummer
     , rg_kto_blz
     , rg_kto_bankname
     , logofile
     , logolink
     , url
     , agb
     , kaution
     , DATE_FORMAT(time, "%d.%m.%y %H:%i:%s")
     , DATE(rg_print, "%d.%m.%y %H:%i:%s")
  FROM forms_user_reg a
  LEFT 
  JOIN 1_additional_data b 
    ON a.urn = b.urn
 ORDER 
    BY turnier DESC 
     , time ASC
 LIMIT 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

The problem is with the 'if'. You are missing the expr3 part. So, you need to supply what to do if turnier does not equal that.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement suggests that:

> if turnier = "Company Friends", substitute it with "Company".

Therefore:

```
SELECT "Company", salutation, chrname, name...
```

However, there's nothing there to be substituted if turnier doesn't match "Company Friends" - no ELSE to the IF, so to speak.

> if turnier <> "Company Friends" then do what?

So,

```
SELECT ?, salutation, chrname, name...
```